# Why JSTL(1.0) functions taglib do not work in jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl, jstl-functions

Functions taglib is not working for jstl comparison.
uri : `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>`
i have included the jstl.jar in my lib folder and in order to check its version i extracted the jar and the MANIFEST.MF shows the below details :

> Specification Version : 1.0
>   Implementation version : 1.0.6

When i tried the above configuration to do a case insensitive comparison as :

```
<c:when test="${fn:toLowerCase(MYVAL) == 'myval'}">
```

It gives me below error :

```
EL functions are not supported.
```

Comment: Where did you read that JSTL 1.0 would be the correct version to use for that URI? Pick [1.2](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar) instead.

Comment: i just added both the specification version and implementation version that i found in MANIFEST.MF